# Skip words/vary word order in search for autocomplete suggestions

Tags: search

I'm using an Entity Reference field which searches taxonomy terms of type Person to suggest options for  autocompletion.

Let's say, i have the following terms (Persons):
 - Jason Jay Smith
-  John Jacob Andrews... etc.

When I input "Jason Ja..." in the field, the autocompletion works fine and suggests me the Smith guy. 
But if i input "Jason Smi...", the term won't be found because the word Jay is skipped.
How can i fix this?

Or generally, how can i implement a better autocomplete search? My terms are composed of a number of words and searching by just one word or a fixed word order is definitely not enough

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would require a different selection handler. Look at class Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection to see how the default selection handler works. In particular you need to create a different buildEntityQuery method. I don't know of any module that provides a handler to do this, and I'm not sure how I would go about accomplishing it myself. Sorry I can't give a more satisfactory answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any info is appreciated